# Leaves display in Fullcalendar

Tags: php, fullcalendar

I am working on a small php app, where users can set leave days.
I am storing them in a db table.
Now I want to use FullCalendar to visualise the employees which are currently on holiday.
I have `calendar-view.php` with this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Employee Leave Calendar</title>
    <link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/5.x/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
</head>
<body>
    <div id='calendar'></div>

    <!-- FullCalendar JS -->
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/5.x/main.min.js'></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            
            var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
            var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
                events: 'calendar.php' //  PHP script
            });
            calendar.render();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and my `calendar.php`:

```
<?php

include 'config.php';
$month = date('m');
$year = date('Y');

$sql = "SELECT user_id, applicant, leave_type, start_date, end_date FROM leave_requests WHERE MONTH(start_date) = :month AND YEAR(start_date) = :year";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(['month' => $month, 'year' => $year]);

$leaves = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$events = [];
foreach ($leaves as $leave) {
    $events[] = [
        'title' => "{$leave['applicant']} ({$leave['leave_type']})",
        'start' => $leave['start_date'],
        'end' => $leave['end_date'], 
        'allDay' => true
    ];
}

echo json_encode($events);
?>
```

When I open calendar.php via browser I get data like this:

```
**[{"title":"UserX (annual)","start":"2024-01-28","end":"2024-01-30","allDay":true},{"title":"UserX(sick)","start":"2024-01-21","end":"2024-01-27","allDay":true}]**
```

When I open calendar-view.php in my browser I see just white screen and in the console, I have this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: FullCalendar is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (calendar-view.php:19:28)
```

I am doing something wrong but I don't know what?

Comment: I found the problem.
The links I was used were not valid.
Now everything is fine

Comment: I was going to say... `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/5.x/main.min.css` clearly isn't a valid URL. Use the latest edition of version 6. CDN links are available from the fullCalendar documentation.

Comment: I just place this one now:
`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@6.1.10/index.global.min.js"></script>`  is this the correct one ?
With this one, I have a working solution.

Comment: At the of writing this comment, that is the latest version, yes